# OpenCV in Electric

Tags: ros, opencv, rosdep, ros-electric, linuxmint

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recompiling under Electric I'm getting the following OpenCV error:

```
Failed to find rosdep opencv2.3 for package...
```

It seems the the OpenCV2 package is deprecated.  What do I need to do to move to the new regime?

When using rosdep install opencv2, the following errors occur:

```
Invalid identifier found [lucid] when processing rosdep boost.  
{{{
{'lucid': {'apt': {'packages': ['libboost1.40-all-dev']}}, 'maverick': {'apt': {'packages': ['libboost1.42-all-dev']}}, 'natty': {'apt': {'packages': ['libboost1.42-all-dev']}}}
}}}

Invalid identifier found [lucid] when processing rosdep opencv2.3.  
{{{
{'lucid': {'apt': {'packages': ['libopencv2.3-dev=2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-1~lucid']}}, 'maverick': {'apt': {'packages': ['libopencv2.3-dev=2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-1~maverick']}}, 'natty': {'apt': {'packages': ['libopencv2.3-dev=2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-1~natty']}}}
}}}

Invalid identifier found [lucid] when processing rosdep eigen.  
{{{
{'lucid': {'apt': {'packages': ['libeigen3-dev=3.0.1-1+ros4~lucid']}}, 'maverick': {'apt': {'packages': ['libeigen3-dev=3.0.1-1+ros4~maverick']}}, 'natty': {'apt': {'packages': ['libeigen3-dev=3.0.1-1+ros4~natty']}}}
}}}

Failed to find rosdep opencv2.3 for package opencv2 on OS:ubuntu version:11.04
rosdep install ERROR:
failed to install opencv2.3
```

When using rosdep install cv_bridge the following occurs:

```
Invalid identifier found [lucid] when processing rosdep boost.  
{{{
{'lucid': {'apt': {'packages': ['libboost1.40-all-dev']}}, 'maverick': {'apt': {'packages': ['libboost1.42-all-dev']}}, 'natty': {'apt': {'packages': ['libboost1.42-all-dev']}}}
}}}

Invalid identifier found [lucid] when processing rosdep opencv2.3.  
{{{
{'lucid': {'apt': {'packages': ['libopencv2.3-dev=2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-1~lucid']}}, 'maverick': {'apt': {'packages': ['libopencv2.3-dev=2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-1~maverick']}}, 'natty': {'apt': {'packages': ['libopencv2.3-dev=2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-1~natty']}}}
}}}

Invalid identifier found [lucid] when processing rosdep eigen.  
{{{
{'lucid': {'apt': {'packages': ['libeigen3-dev=3.0.1-1+ros4~lucid']}}, 'maverick': {'apt': {'packages': ['libeigen3-dev=3.0.1-1+ros4~maverick']}}, 'natty': {'apt': {'packages': ['libeigen3-dev=3.0.1-1+ros4~natty']}}}
}}}

Failed to find rosdep opencv2.3 for package cv_bridge on OS:ubuntu version:11.04
rosdep install ERROR:
failed to install opencv2.3
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11110/opencv-in-electric/) by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 995 on 2011-09-03

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2011-09-03**:
OS is Linux Mint 11

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-09-03**:
Could you include your OS, CMakeLists and manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It has been replaced with a `rosdep` [dependency on the system version](http://www.ros.org/wiki/opencv2#OpenCV_in_Electric).

Follow-up information suggests that `rosdep` is having trouble identifying your Mint 11 version of Linux. It seems to think you are running Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty). Presumably, [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/1109/compiling-on-linux-mint-11) is related somehow.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2011-09-04**:
It's not the same as the debian.py issue, which is fixed in Electric, but it's probably something similar.

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2011-09-04**:
Yes I think you're right.  Mint 11 is really just Ubuntu 11.04 without Unity and with a different menu system.  It looks as if I can compile without using --rosdep-install, so this is really an issue with detecting the relevant dependent packages.

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2011-09-03**:
See above.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-09-03**:
What happens if you type: `rosdep install cv_bridge`?

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2011-09-03**:
I added the following to CMakeLists.txt: find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS})

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-09-03**:
Did you do the `CMakeLists.txt` changes?

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2011-09-03**:
Even including those depends I still get the same failure.  Should I have a stack.xml file?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-09-03**:
The page @joq linked to contains a sample manifest.xml fragment: http://www.ros.org/wiki/opencv2#Package.2BAC8-stack_dependencies

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2011-09-03**:
So what should I be declaring within manifest.xml ?